# Как удалить определенные классы элементов из документа?

Tags: html, jquery

В документе есть классы (отвечают за анимацию), на маленьких экранах я хочу убрать анимацию. За "старт" анимации отвечает скрипт, который привязан к классам анимации. Т.е., если убрать эти классы анимации - скрипт не сработает.

Вопрос, как мне найти в документе эти классы и удалить их?

Comment: а вы знаете список этих классов? проще всего вынести скрипт который отвечает за старт анимации в отдельный файл и при маленьких экранах не подключать его

Comment: Проблема в удалении классов, или в удалении классов, при определённом размере экрана?

Comment: ну там будет определенный размер экрана, при котором они удаляются при resize'e. Список классов известен. Получается, что я сам себя удаляю, типа:
$('.test').removeClass('test'). А вот более грамотный способ есть? 
А как тогда подгрузить/не подгрузить файл скрипта, при определенном условии размера экрана?

Comment: может лучше модифицировать поведение скрипта в зависимости от размера экрана?

Comment: уже модифицировал, но хотел просто узнать возможно ли провернуть такое.

Comment: возможно ли удалить класс? ну да - http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если есть список классов можно их удалять так

к примеру нужно удалить класс `green`

```
$(".green").removeClass("green");
```

---

Можно вот так удалять по списку классов

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var arr = ["white", "green"];
  $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
    $('.' + val).removeClass(val);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green">
  <div class="red green">
    <p class="white red">hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотел узнать можно ли без указания самого себя удалять себя. Что-то типа $(doсument).removeClass.. и перечень классов, которые нужно удалить.

Comment: @NeedHate проверьте **update** поставил пример

Comment: ВОТъ! Совершенно другое дело. Теперь точно помогло. Спасибо. Заслуженный плюс.